# How to Import Google doc text into Email draft using Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, gmail-api, google-workspace

I'm pretty new to Google Apps Script as a whole. And the main reason I hope to learn is to be able to import the text written in a google doc file into an email draft that i'm writing (so as to continue building off that main function later on). Originally, I wanted a widget within the gmail compose box. But after scouring the web for a solution, I'm settling for just about anything.

Just to be clear, I don't want the .docx file attached to the email only the option to pick a specific doc and import whatever is written within it.

Thanks in advance and sorry for not being able to provide sufficient code progress!

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the [Document Service Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/#top_of_page) for manipulation of documents.

> This service allows scripts to create, access, and modify Google Docs
>   files.

There are available sample code in the said documentation.

After manipulating the desired document, you can refer to this [Class GmailDraft Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-draft) to paste the information you got from the documents.

> A user-created draft message in a user's Gmail account.

Hope this documents can help you further.